# When my page loads it displays the previous mysql query result not the current one

Tags: php, mysql, function, echo

When you go from the previous page to the current page it will autmatically fill a div with a specific mysql query result, the only issue is that when the page it initially loads it displays the previous query result, you have to refresh the page to get the current result and I dont understand why.

In my php at the top of the page I call a function from another page. This functin checks my database for a specific result and returns it, that result is then echo'd into a div class.

```
<--index.php-->
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/myFunctions.php');
$desc = returnDesc();
?>
...
...
<body>
<div class = "descBox">
    <?php echo $desc; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

and the function itself is..

```
<--myFunctions.php-->
function returnDesc()
{ 
    $con = connection();
    $planetMoon = (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Sol, Star, Planet, Moon FROM MK1 WHERE id = 1"));
    if ($planetMoon->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $planetMoon->fetch_assoc()) {
            $descSol = $row["Sol"];
            $descStar = $row["Star"];
            $descPlanet = $row["Planet"];
            $descMoon = $row["Moon"];
            $Desc = (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Description FROM DescBox WHERE Sol = '$descSol' AND Star = '$descStar' AND Planet = '$descPlanet' AND Moon = '$descMoon'"));
            if ($Desc->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $Desc->fetch_assoc()) {
                    return $descPlanetMoon = $row["Description"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: what happens if you change the return to an echo?

Comment: It doesn't work, the 'return' simply sets a final value for the function 'returnDesc()'

Comment: exactly dont set a value just echo the sql results and just call your function returnDesc(); as a void

Comment: Oh i see, I did try that however it broke all of the other functions in 'myFunctions.php' and wouldn't send the user to the page where i try to return the function 'returnDesc()'

Comment: looks like you need to build an array of values doing return inside of your while doesnt make sens it will only return the first one

Comment: @rojobo Sorry I dont understand when you mean?

Comment: return $descPlanetMoon = $row["Description"];--->>will only return the first result in the list

Comment: @rojobo It doesn't though, it will always return the correct record however you have to refresh the page for the most recent record to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
function returnDesc()
{ 
    $con = connection();
    $descPlanetMoon = array();
    $planetMoon = (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Sol, Star, Planet, Moon FROM MK1 WHERE id = 1"));
    if ($planetMoon->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $planetMoon->fetch_assoc()) {
            $descSol = $row["Sol"];
            $descStar = $row["Star"];
            $descPlanet = $row["Planet"];
            $descMoon = $row["Moon"];
            $Desc = (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Description FROM DescBox WHERE Sol = '$descSol' AND Star = '$descStar' AND Planet = '$descPlanet' AND Moon = '$descMoon'"));
            if ($Desc->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $Desc->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $descPlanetMoon[] += $row["Description"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $descPlanetMoon;
}
```

Comment: This will only display 'Array' though

Comment: do you know what a loop is?

Comment: Yes, however a variable contained inside of a nested statement cannot be used outside of that statement, probably why it is only returning 'Array'. Thank you for trying however.

Comment: I highly suggest you take some sort of coding courses